# custom x axis tooltip for nvd3 scatter chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, nvd3.js, scatter-plot

I am using nvd3 Scatter Chart and I see that the tooltip content can be customized using the following function.

```
chart.tooltipContent(function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
    return '<p><strong>' + key + '</strong></p>' +
           '<p>' + e.value + ' in the month ' + x + '</p>';
    });
```

When the mouse moves over the bubble, the custom tooltip content and the x-value and y-value of the point/bubble are highlighted/shown. Instead of displaying the x-axis label, I want to display custom content. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: can you please put this up on a fiddle.

Comment: try checking their source files for the tooltip here : https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/tooltip.js

Answer (score 12):

`chart.tooltipContent` is deprecated in nvd3 now. To use custom content in the tooltip, you will want to use

```
chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function(obj) {code to build tooltip})
```

In order to see what data you have to work with in your function, start by adding this line:

```
chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (obj) { return JSON.stringify(obj)})
```

and then you'll be able to hover over your data point and see the object you are working with.

Look in src/tooltip.js at the default function used for contentGenerator [starting around line 76](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/tooltip.js#L76) to see a great example of the kind of function you could build and pass to contentGenerator

Here is the relevant section in the documentation [documentation](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#tooltip)

Comment: "recommending "return JSON.stringify(obj)}"  .. that is a good debug step